# How to get minutes from Joda-Time that is not formatted

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, date-difference

I have the following:

```
DateTime startDate = session.getProgramSessionDetail().getStartDate();
DateTime endDate = session.getProgramSessionDetail().getEndDate();
Minutes minutes = Minutes.minutesBetween(startDate, endDate);

String testing = minutes.toString();

logger.debug("Minutes :: " + testing);
```

The output is:

> Minutes :: PT90M

I want the output to be just `90` so I can convert to `int` and use in some other fields.

I could parse it out but is there not a way to just get the plain numerical value.

Comment: minutes.getMinutes() will give difference in mins

Answer (score 0):

The [`Minutes::toString()` method](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Minutes.html#toString--) returns the minutes value as a [ISO8601 duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). In this case, `PT90M` means "a duration of 90 minutes".

To get just the minutes value, you can use the [`getMinutes()` method](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Minutes.html#getMinutes--), that returns the value as `int`, so you can print it like this:

```
int value = minutes.getMinutes();
logger.debug("Minutes :: " + value);
```

The output will be:

> Minutes :: 90

As this method already returns an `int`, you don't need to convert it.